# starting another program with arguments from qt app

Tags: c++, qt

I have a simple app

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//cout << argv[1];
cout << "hello world";
getchar();
}
```

and I want to start it from qt program using

```
QProcess *process= new QProcess(this);
QString appPath= "..../.../TestApp2.exe";
process->start(appPath);
```

the problem is that my program dosen't starts, even without arguments. I have tried to start a standard app like "calc" and it worked. How could I start my app with specific args (sure after uncommitting the second line of the first snippet)

Comment: Is `"..../.../TestApp2.exe"` supposed to represent the full path to the executable or is that the actual code you are using?

Comment: Set the path where exec exists using ->QProcess::setWorkingDirectory() .

Comment: it contains the absolute file path but i didn't include it here since its irrelevant. the same path could be executed by copying it  to the command line without problems

Comment: I have tried using QProcess::setWorkingDirectory() and using QDir::setCurrent() but both didn't work.

Comment: You need to connect to some/all of the signals emitted by `QProcess` to find out what's happening.  Also check the value returned by [`QProcess::error`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#error).

Comment: i have tried it but it seems it executes without any errors, however the external program still didn't get executed

Comment: How would you tell that it is not starting? `QProcess` hides the console window for the process it starts and redirects its STDOUT/STDERR output to the main application for you to read there. **So, if you are expecting to see a console window when the process starts, you are wrong**. This maybe the reason why applications like "calc" start while your console application does not.

Comment: ok you are right because actually what I am trying to do is to start my visualisation app (vtk, openvr, htc vive ) ... I get other error messeges regarding missing libs but it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to start a standard app like "calc" and it worked. How could I start my app

Your application is a console application.

`QProcess` hides the console window for console applications and redirects their STDOUT/STDERR for you to read them (using [`readAllStandardOutput()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput), [`readAllStandardError()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError), ...). and whatever you [`write()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) to your `QProcess` goes to its STDIN. **So, if you are expecting to see a console window when the process starts, you are wrong.**

If you want to start a console application without hiding its console window, you can use [`QProcess::startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1):

```
QProcess::startDetached("test.exe");
```

But most of the times there is no reason to do so. `QProcess` is meant to be used from a GUI application in order to start a process behind the scenes, and take a result from it. After that, you can display the result to the user the way you like. A user of a GUI application usually doesn't expect a console window asking him/her for input every now and then. Also, He/She wouldn't expect to see the result in a console window.