# How to launch a new process from QT

Tags: c++, qt, process

I am trying to make a Qt program and at the beginning of the application I need to start an executable made with C++, Cuda and OpenGL. This executable will write some data in a file and after this I print this data in same Qt labels.

I can't understand why my executable doesn't run. I found this example on the internet:

```
    QProcess*   process = new QProcess();
    QString program = "c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe";
    process->start(program);
```

For calc.exe it works, but when I replace the link with my executable:

```
         e:\\VS\\Licenta\\Benchmark1\\Debug\\mainPro.exe
```

Doesn't start anymore. And also I would like to know if there is a possibility to make the interface to wait until the executable is finished writing the file.

Thank you very much.

Comment: will adding line `process->waitForFinished();` after `process->start(program);` fix your issue? It waits in current thread untill process is finished (you might not want to run this in your UI thread, unless you want to freeze UI)

Comment: Does your executable start if you run it from, say, the command line?

Comment: Yes, the executable dosen't have errors and run ok.

Comment: I have try to run a simple hello world in C and also doesn't work. Appears to run just executable with interface because i try to run a executable made in C# and works. This is strange.

Comment: @Adi , If the application you want to start is a console application, You may want to use `QProcess::startDetached("path/to/mainpro.exe");`. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40655330/2666212).

Comment: @Mike works how you say. The problem is that my console application pop up a scene in  OpenGl. If i open just a console application works with startDetached but if my application start a scen in OpenGL dosen;t work any more

Comment: @Adi, "*doesn't work*" is not a good description for problems, always try to write as much details as you can if you can't provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So, what does `startDetached()` return? what do you exactly get when you use your first approach?

Comment: ok, so the first version works for executable with interface, the second works just for console application (the version with startDetached(). I  have created a simple hello word application and works). My project is a console application but run a scene with openGl and CUDA and dosen't start with any of this solution. startDetached() return unknown error.

Comment: If i am trying something like this :    qDebug() << (process_->state() == QProcess::NotRunning); the return value from the call is false

Comment: I have try more and now say : QIODevice::read (QProcess): device not open .

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thx